# Using requests.get() in python to view video

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests
from sys import exit

url = 'www.videohere.com'

while(True):
    try:
        requests.get(url)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
```

*Ok so i'm trying to use requests to view this video on this page but like just basically stay on the page as if it is watching i have no clue on how to go about doing it, so if anyone could give any suggestions or show a little poc please do! thanks guys.

Comment: Did you try using urlib as mentioned here https://qr.ae/TWK37b

Comment: `requests` is for HTTP. Viewing videos on the web is more than just downloading files from a server. Maybe look at this to get an impression: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl

Comment: Can you please add more details so we can understand what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Please provide a valid video example to your code. Also add more context related to the problem of requesting and playing this video.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by using `requests.get()` to view video?

If you would like to make to the progress bar (I don't know what it is named, hope you can understand) to move on, you just need to post some data to the server. You don't need to really "get" the video.

For example, on a Chinese video sharing website BILIBILI, it use the `heartbeat` to record where you were. It will help if you close the webpage and open it again, it will notify you that you could restore to the second where you were watching.

[image: BILIBILI POST]

On different websites, the method might be different. On YouTube, the key is encrypted, so it might be a little bit challenging to pretent your cralwer as a real person watching the video.

For the site you mentioned as `mixed.com`, in Developer Tools, you could find the following:
[image: Destination to Cound Users]

To give your a brief of posting data on this site, the url of site is

```
https://browser.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/?cors=true&content-type=application/x-json-stream&client-id=NO_AUTH&client-version=1DS-Web-JS-2.0.0-rc3&apikey=1918f1672f934c5ca6b2669551351de2-b61c1f8e-4440-4e53-8e38-b46e4c88a7e5-7038&upload-time=1569343709069&w=0
```

Once you are in someone's websites, you can find out your browser keeps posting data to this target url every several seconds. Personally speaking, I think it is a tool to record the number of users watching in this room.

For `https://browser.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/` this part, we shall have the same url, but the residual should be generated by the contents in your requests headers.

What's more, the apikey and the payload in the following picture tell me that it is really tough for people to use crawler to pretending a real user.

[image: Payload in Requests Headers]

Most part of it could be easily fetched from the website, but it might require delication for not making mistakes.

Comment: i was trying to make it for mixer.com to view someones page / stream

Comment: I have already modified the answer. I suppose it would help you in get the goal.